# Switch case with character and ascii value behave same in java

Tags: java, char, switch-statement, ascii

How switch cases with ascii value or character behave same?

How case convert internally ascii to char or char to ascii

```
public class Rq200_150 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (Character cRef = 'A'; cRef < 'F'; cRef++)
            switch (cRef) {
            default:
                System.out.println((char) ('a' + cRef - 'A'));
                break;
            case 'B':
                System.out.println(cRef);
                break;
            case 68:
                System.out.println(cRef);
                break;
            case 67:
                System.out.println(cRef);
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the question/problem? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Though I put case 68 which is ascii of character D it is considering as case D..   so  my question is how switch case come to know that 68 is ascii value for D... and we are providing cRef i.e. character for switch case then how it is accepting 68,67 number cases

Comment: 68 is the unicode (and ascii) value of `D` and `char` can be converted to an int: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: Means switch case internally do this conversion while execution??

Comment: See [Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html). (ASCII has nothing to do with it.)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, a char is an unsigned integer in the range 0 to 65535 (it's 0xffff)

> char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive). (from [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html))

which prints out as the Unicode character corresponding to that number, assuming your computer supports Unicode.

The values 0 to 127 (0x7f) correspond to Unicode's original precursor (ASCII) and 0 to 255 (0xff) is extended ASCII.

So because your program is set to case "68" or 'D' it'll be read either way as the same thing.

Hope this answers the question

Comment: is conversion vice versa?

Comment: or it coverts char to int only... i.e. 'D' as 68... not 68 as 'D'

Comment: Yes it is the conversion goes both ways

Comment: but when i use switch case with int and provide case 68  then it is printing 68 only.. not character D

Comment: `for(int cRef='A'; cRef<'F';cRef++)
  switch(cRef){
  default:System.out.println((char)('a'+cRef-'A'));break;
  case 'B':System.out.println(cRef);break;
  case 68:System.out.println(cRef);break;
  case 67:System.out.println(cRef);
  }
 }

Comment: for this question, i think you have an answer

Answer (score 0):

The char primitive is actually just a number. The java vm turns any value of the form 'x' into its corresponding number equivalent for any sort of comparison. Thus, 68 = 'D', so putting either one into a switch statement will catch that scenario. Thats why you can do math on chars; chars are just numbers.

Comment: is conversion vice versa?

Comment: or it coverts char to int only... i.e. 'D' as 68... not 68 as 'D'

Comment: It will convert to whatever is needed at that point. If you print out the number 68, it will just print out the nunber, since it doesnt know you want a char. You should use "char" instead of "Character", you don't need the object version, and it is more predictable.

Answer (score 0):

Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands of certain operators:

for example:
The numerical comparison operators <, <=, >, and >=

> if any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing
>   conversion (§5.1.8).
>
> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or
>   both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>
> Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted
>   to float.
>
> Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted
>   to long.
>
> Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

So in this case, It will be executed to int.

This is a broad topic .I recommend you to visit [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.13)